# $SU(n)$ character variety of integral homology spheres

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, rt.representation-theory, gt.geometric-topology

Suppose that $Y$ is an integral homology $3$-sphere. Is it true that, for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there is always an irreducible representation $\pi_{1}(Y) \rightarrow SU(n)$?

I'm also happy to see the answer when the Lie group is replaced by $SL(n, \mathbb{C})$ or $PSL(n, \mathbb{C})$, but keeping irreducible unchanged.

Edit: In this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.08530), Zentner proved the statement positively for $SL(2, \mathbb{C})$. It might be true that there is a threshold $n$ such that there is no more $SU(N)$ irreducible representations for $N \geq n$. The question was stated in this way because constructing counter-examples to the vanishing statement might be easier.

Comment: The Poincaré homology sphere has fundamental group the binary icosahedral group, which is finite and therefore admits only finitely many irreducible representations.

Comment: Yes, my motivation of asking this question is to see if this failure holds in much more generality.

Comment: So you are asking: for all $n \in \mathbb N$, is there an integral homology 3-sphere $Y$ with an irreducible $\pi_1(Y) \to SU(n)$?

Comment: No, I am asking if $Y$ is fixed, can you find such representations. As you pointed out this is not true if Y is the Poincar\'e homology sphere, the question is about whether this failure holds for all $Y$.

Comment: It should be true that for a given closed 3-manifold with infinite fundamental group, there is an irreducible $SU(N)$ representation for $N$ sufficiently large. But the case of homology spheres and $n=2$ is a well-known open question, so I think your question as stated is probably difficult.